# Get back the good old non-interactive diff tool in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

Since a recent upgrade, Mercurial gives me a graphical interface to merge/conflicts. I don't want it; I just want the files marked with <<<< ==== >>>> in the good old fashion, to let me go through the conflicts with leisure, instead of the order some crummy diff tool decides. How do I get it back? The help I find is all about switching to the exact tools I do not want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `[ui]` section of your `.hgrc`, add

```
merge=internal:merge
```

See [mercurial docs](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MergeToolConfiguration#Internal_merge_with_conflict_markers).

I'm with you about this choice of tools.  The merge tools are clearly very clever, but if I've got a conflict like this, it's typically because I've messed up somehow, at least a little bit, and I'd like to fix things up *nice and slow*, so I'm confident I know what's where and why.